# An example of a valuation function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $F$ be the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{N}$. For $f,g\in F$ define

$\text{val}(f,g)=\begin{cases}\min\{n\in\Bbb N~:~f(n)\neq g(n)\}&\text{if}~f\neq g\\\infty&\text{if}~f=g\end{cases}$

where $\infty$ is a new symbol.

Question. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $s_n\in F$ be the constant function that takes the value $n$ for all variables. For $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ find $val(s_n,s_m)$.

My answer. Assume $s_n\neq s_m$. Note that $s_n(x)=n$ for all $x$ and $s_m(x)=m$ for all $x$. So, what I say about $\min\{n\in\Bbb N~:~f(n)\neq g(n)\}$? Can you help?

Comment: Hint:  consider two cases, $m=n$ and $m\neq n$.  Side note:  people differ on whether or not $0$ is a natural number.  That will make a difference as to the answer here.

Comment: @lulu if $m=n$, then min of the set is zero, right? So what can I think $m\neq n$?

Comment: No...if $m=n$ then $s_m=s_n$ and your definition then says...

Comment: @lulu probably, I couldn't understand the function.. Can you give trivial example the function?

Comment: To stress:  you should edit your post to state whether you are defining $0\in \mathbb N$ or $0\notin \mathbb N$.  We can't help you with that...I'd say (just guessing) that people are roughly evenly split between the two conventions.

Comment: The functions are constant!  If $n=1$, then $s_n=s_1$ just takes every value to $1$.  Thus $s_1(1)=1,s_1(2)=1, s_1(1381791)=1$ and so on.

Comment: @lulu in your opinion, what should it be ($0\in\mathbb{N}$, or  $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$?), that is how should it be?

Comment: Well, personally I always have $0\notin \mathbb N$, but then I am really, really old and conventions that were standard in the past have shifted.  It's not a question of right versus wrong.   If you have a text you should just check to see which convention they are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We split in two cases, either $m = n$ or $m \neq n$.
If $m=n$, we find that $s_n(k) = s_m(k)$ for every natural number $k$, and thus we find that $\text{val}(s_n,s_m) = \infty. $
We now consider the case that $m \neq n$. Then, $s_m(k) \neq s_n(k)$ for every natural number $k$. Thus, val($s_n,s_m) = 0$ (or 1, depending on how you define the natural numbers).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there is a poor choice of variable names in your question. Rather than $s_n$ and $s_m$ write $s_p(n)$ and $s_m(n)$. Then if $m=p$, $val(s_m,s_p) = \infty$ since $s_p(n) = s_m(n) = m$ for all $n$.

If, say, $m<p$, then $s_m(0) = m < s_p(0) = p$, so $val(s_m,s_p) = 0$.

Comment: how did $val(s_m,s_p)$ is zero as your opinion, can you explain? I couldn't understand.

Comment: since $s_m (0)=m<s_m (0)=p$, so I think, $val(s_m,s_p)=m$. Can you explain, how did it get zero?

Comment: I understand your confusion. Notice that the valuation function gives you back the lowest INPUT $n$ such that $f(n) \neq g(n)$. It does NOT give you the value of $f(n)$ where $f(n) \neq g(n)$.

Comment: okey thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

Just conceptually, think of what the function $val(f,g)$ is trying to output: it outputs the smallest ('first') value of $n$ for which $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are not the same. So, if $f$ and $g$ are both constant functions, but different, then of course they are different for *any* $n$, and hence $val(f,g)$ in that case will output the smallest value that $n$ can take on ... which is either $0$ or $1$, depending on how you define the natural numbers.